How to us a Tailwind/Html input with a rails form - for date picker
I want to replace my form.date_field for a Tailwind date picker, it's got nicer styling.
I have it working in the view, so know the supporting java script is fine.
It pops up and I can select a date, but it doesn't submit the date when the form is submitted as I don't know how to connect this input to my form (form_with(model: equipment)
Original Code
<%= form_with(model: equipment) do |form| %>
  <% if equipment.errors.any? %>
    <div style="color: red">
      <h2><%= pluralize(equipment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this equipment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% equipment.errors.each do |error| %>
          <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="mb-6">
   <%= form.label :sale_date,"Date of Sale", class: label_class%>
    <div class="mt-1">
     <%= form.date_field :sale_date, class: input_class  %>
    </div> 
 </div>

  <div>
     <%= form.submit "Save Record", class: form_button_class %>
  </div>
 <% end %>

New Code to replace :sale_date date_field
    <div class="relative max-w-sm">
    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 start-0 flex items-center ps-3.5 pointer-events-none">
    <svg class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <path d="M20 4a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-2V1a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v1h-3V1a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v1H6V1a1 1 0 0 0-2 0v1H2a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v2h20V4ZM0 18a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V8H0v10Zm5-8h10a1 1 0 0 1 0 2H5a1 1 0 0 1 0-2Z"/>
    </svg>
   </div>
    <input datepicker type="text" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full ps-10 p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="Select date">
    </div>

How do I link this code to the rails form
<%= form_with(model: equipment) do |form| %>
I've tried to read up on html forms but can't make sense of how to declare the
I have tried adding name="sale_date" to input datepicker
and
data-value=<% :sale_date %>
It's not getting picked up when I submit the form.
